# Magento: How to change this code to get the recently viewed products?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using the code below to get the most viewed products:

```
<?php 
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addOrderedQty()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addViewsCount();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

What can be changed on this code in order to get the recently viewed instead of most viewed? I already have a template to show it. For most viewed, I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store/).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

"->addViewsCount()" is the special sauce here to the filter.

Please review: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-most-viewed-products/

Which basically does the Above, but with a Timeframe added to it.

```
public function getMostViewedProducts()
{  
    // number of products to display
    $productCount = 5;

    // store ID
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    // get today and last 30 days time
    $today = time();
    $last = $today - (60*60*24*30);

    $from = date("Y-m-d", $last);
    $to = date("Y-m-d", $today);

    // get most viewed products for last 30 days
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
        ->setPageSize($productCount);

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
            ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    return $products;
}
```